# Prohibition of marrying a Non-Jew

Tags: intermarriage

What is the biblical prohibition of marrying a Non-jew, i.e. what verse is one violating?

Answer (score 0):

The [Sefer Hachinuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Chinuch) lists marrying a Non-Jew as a prohibition from the verse in [Deut. 7:3](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.7.3?lang=en&with=Sefer%20HaChinukh&lang2=he)

(*Source provided from [Sefaria.org](http://www.sefaria.org/texts)*)

> **ספר החינוך תכ״ז:א׳**
>
> **לא להתחתן בעובדי אלילים - שלא נתחתן עם האמות, וכתב הרמב''ם זכרונו לברכה (מאיסורי ביאה יב א) לא עם שבעה עממים ולא עם שאר האמות, שנאמר (דברים ז ג) ולא תתחתן בם. וענין החתנות הוא, שיתן בתו לבנו או בנו לבתו, וכמו שבאר הכתוב (שם) בתך לא תתן לבנו ובתו לא תקח לבנך. וכל שכן המזדוג עמהם, שהוא בעצמו בכלל האסור, ואמרינן במסכת עבודה זרה (לו, ב) דרך חתנות אסרה תורה, ואף על פי שהכתוב הזה דלא תתחתן בשבעה עממים הוא דכתיב ובגרותן דוקא, והכי משמע להו לרבנן שאמרו בגמרא (יבמות עו, א) בגרותן אית להו חתנות, בגיותן לית להו חתנות, במה שחזר הכתוב בתך לא תתן לבנו ובתו לא תקח לבנך ירבה שבעה עממים וכל שאר האמות באסור אף בגרות, אבל שבעה עממין נאסרו אף בגרותן לפי שהיו עקר עבודה זרה ויסודה הראשון, ושאר עממין מתרין בגרות, ואסור זה יהיה דוקא כשהוא מיחדה לו לאשה, אבל הבא על הגויה דרך מקרה, כאדם שבא על זוגתו שלא בפרהסיא, אין בזה אלא אסור דבריהם, והוא אסור נשג''ז (נדה, שפחה, גויה, זונה). המזכר בעבודה זרה (שם).** ‏

Hope this helps